# Remove Spacing Between Text on copied Input

Tags: javascript, html, css

With help from StackOverflow members I have a search box where a user can input text which is copied over into other search boxes.

Id like to remove the space between the text on the second box. So if you were searching "Star Wars"

1. Copied content would say "Stars Wars"
2. Copied content would say "StarsWars"

Is this possible or too complex?

Example Code:

```js
const otherSearchBars = document.querySelectorAll('.copied-content');
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function() {
  const c = this;
  otherSearchBars.forEach(e => e.value = c.value);
})
```

```css
.input-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-basis: 70%;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Main Search Box</h1>
<main class="input-container">
  <input type="text" id="searchinput" spellcheck="true" class="mainsearch" autofocus placeholder="Search Now.">
</main>
<br>

<form action="https://www.reddit.com/search" target="_blank" data-searchmethod="getParameters">
  <input class="copied-content" type="text" name="q">
  <button>Search Reddit</button>
</form>

<form action="https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/" target="_blank" data-searchmethod="getParameters">
  <input class="copied-content" type="text" name="q">
  <button>Search Instagram</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I edited your code a bit. I hope its useful for you.

```js
let search = document.querySelectorAll(".copied-content")

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function(){
      
      search.forEach((x, i) => {
          if(i % 2 == 0){
            x.value = this.value
          }
          else x.value = this.value.split(" ").filter(Boolean).join("")
      })
})
```

```html
          <h1>
       Main Search Box
      </h1>
      <main class="input-container">
            <input type="text" id="searchinput" spellcheck="true" class="mainsearch" autofocus
                placeholder="Search Now.">
        </main>
       
       
       </br>
        
           <form action="https://www.reddit.com/search"target="_blank" data-searchmethod="getParameters">
            <input class="copied-content" type="text" name="q">
            <button>Search Reddit</button>
        </form>
        
               <form action="https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/"target="_blank" data-searchmethod="getParameters">
            <input class="copied-content" type="text" name="q">
            <button>Search Instagram</button>
            
                       <form action="https://www.reddit.com/search"target="_blank" data-searchmethod="getParameters">
            <input class="copied-content" type="text" name="q">
            <button>Search Instagram2</button>
        </form>
        
               <form action="https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/"target="_blank" data-searchmethod="getParameters">
            <input class="copied-content" type="text" name="q">
            <button>Search Reddit2</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Hi Yahya, this is great thank you. 

What if I have another 10 Inputs that all want to be displayed the same as 'searchReddit' and 2 inputs that want to be displayed the same as 'searchInsta' would they all need different id's? like this 

https://jsfiddle.net/mkt4b87v/

Comment: Do you only want to delete the spaces of the 2nd textboxes? For example : not delete spaces of first textbox , delete spaces of second textbox , not delete spaces of third textbox...

Comment: Hi Yahya, would more random

1) spaces, 2) no spaces, 3) spaces, 4) no spaces.  I thought perhaps adding the ID to the inputs with no spaces, but I couldnt get that to work.

Comment: I fixed my code. I hope it can help you